# Apt / Deb Support in Fedora

Tags: fedora, apt, deb

I want to have some apt / debian support in Fedora 18. I know how to use **yum**, and I like it. But not all packages / repositories are available for it. So, I wanna install apt (apt-get) to my Fedora.

But I don't know whether yum integrates well with it or not. If I had the two package managers installed, would my system be messed?

*PS.* I always try to use Fedora / rpm software, but I think it would be much easier to work if I had the two package managers.

### Update - Conclusion

My conclusion is: try to stick and use **yum**, it is more distro friendly and better integrated. If you ever need a package that is not listed in your custom repos (or in the official ones), try to download it and compile it from source. It is better than try to port deb packages to rpm (at least for now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the basic ways that Linux distributions can be divided into groups is whether they are .rpm or .deb based. In other words, whether they're based on Debian or Red Hat (the other great category is SlackWare and its derivatives but they use source packages and are a whole different kettle of fish). Not all package-based Linux distros can be placed in one of these two categories but most can. for a graphical overview, see this [wonderful image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg) from wikipedia.

So, what you are trying to do is not really possible. There *are* ways of installing .deb packages on .rpm-based distros and *vice versa* (have a look at [`alien`](http://joeyh.name/code/alien/)) but not natively. It is not simply a matter of installing `apt` on Fedora or `rpm` on Debian. The way the packages are set up is different.

However, I really really doubt that you will find many packages that do not exist in both .rpm and .deb repositories. Probably, all you need to do is add the right repo. If you cannot find an rpm for a given package in the repository you are using, try [searching for it](http://rpm.pbone.net) and installing manually.

Comment: Thanks for that.

The only problem with installing the packages manually / building them from source is that they won't get updates, because they won't be integrated with the repositories and the package manager itself. It's too easy to find the source of the packages, but it is not very practical to get them updated manually.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Tools/Apt) there is an apt port for fedora, `apt-rpm`, but it has (or had) some downsides compared with yum.
If there are some packages missing I suggest to look if they are available on other repos or you could build them from source.

Comment: This won't help with what's really asked here, which is to install Debian packages on Fedora. apt-rpm installs Fedora RPMs.

Answer (score 1):

As terdon already said, you can not install another package manager on Fedora. But what I would recommend is: add other Repositories. The essential one that provides all the packages Fedora cannot provide itself due to legal issues is [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/). If you need other packages, check the Repositories listed [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Third_party_repositories).

If a package is not included in any repository (rare, but happens), the best thing would be to install it from source.